# Birkat hamazon for chametz on Passover

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, bentching

On Passover, if a Jew consumes Chametz because they have to for Pikuach Nefesh, do they recite Birkat Hamazon afterwards? Of course this would be more than the minimum amount to be liable on Pesach, (again consumed for pikuach nefesh), should they not recite Berakhah for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch (OC [196:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.196.2), [204:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.204.9)) says we make the usual blessings when eating non-kosher out of necessity. Presumably the same would apply to chametz on Pesach.

Comment: Maybe you could argue כיתותי מכתת because there's an issur hanaah and so you didn't eat a kezayis, meaning you'd make a bracha before but not after